# If last item printed on screen by a list in python turtle = value1 then move to a different position and print value 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

Trying to see if its possible to do the following using python turtle graphics (assume modules have been imported already):

```
my_values = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'] #these values are strings 



def heading():
  if my_values == 'value1':
    setheading(90)
    forward(10)
  if my_values == 'value2':
    setheading(0)
    forward(30)
  if my_values == 'value3':
    setheading(270)
    forward(60)

def working_together():
 for loop in range(3):
    write(my_values[value_range], move = False, align = 'center')
    heading()

working_together()
```

The main premise of what im trying to achieve is that if the item last printed on the screen by turtle == valueX then the turtle will then move to a different position. This must loop through until the loop is complete and all values have been printed?

Is this possible in python?

Ive tried the following:

```
def heading():
  if range(my_values == 'value1'):
    setheading(90)
    forward(10)
  if range(my_values == 'value2'):
    setheading(0)
    forward(30)
  if range(my_values == 'value3'):
    setheading(270)
    forward(60)

def heading():
  if range(len(my_values == 'value1')):
    setheading(90)
    forward(10)
  if range(len(my_values == 'value2')):
    setheading(0)
    forward(30)
  if range(len(my_values == 'value3')):
    setheading(270)
    forward(60)
```

Comment: The last element of a list is `list[-1]`. BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in type.

Comment: This feels a bit pseudocodey. What are you [really trying to achieve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) at a high level, please? This makes it easier to provide the best answer. Thanks

Comment: @Barmar I know that, im not trying to see the last item im trying to see if the last item that was printed by the turtle = X then Y

Comment: When the turtle prints something, save it in a global variable.

Comment: `len(my_values == 'value1')` makes no sense. `my_values == 'value1'` returns a boolean, which doesn't have a length.

Comment: Why don't you just pass it as an argument to `heading`?

Comment: @Barmar gonna try passing it as an argument now that would make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it as an argument to `heading()`.

```
def heading(current_value):
  if current_value == 'value1':
    setheading(90)
    forward(10)
  elif current_value == 'value2':
    setheading(0)
    forward(30)
  elif current_value == 'value3':
    setheading(270)
    forward(60)

def working_together():
    for value in my_values:
        write(value, move = False, align = 'center')
        heading(value)

working_together()
```

Comment: yep I did something similar and it works

Comment: If you found a different solution you should post it as an answer of your own. If they're similar enough you should accept this answer to mark the question answered.